# Why does the parent DIV resize while there is still room for the child element to move down?

Tags: css

sorry if this question looks duplicate, but those explanations were in some way different from what I was looking for.

I have a `DIV` that is displayed a `table`. It has two `DIV`s as cells which also have their own `DIV`s inside.

```
    <div class="theTable">
     <div class="theRow">
      <div class="cell1">
       <div class="cell1Content">
        cell one content
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell2">
       <div class="cell2Content">
        cell two content
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Now, when by any means (such as writing, or changing attributes), I enlarge the content of one of these cells (say `cell2`) instead of the content being enlarged from downward, and filling the area of the parent DIV (which is a cell), what happens is that the parent `DIV` actually expands from top. This behavior is not desired. I want the parent `DIV` to stay the same size, and the content to resize from bottom (downward).
I know this can be achieved using, `position:relative, top:2em`, but that's not what I am intending to do, because I do not want to disrupt the flow of the `document`, rather a simple answer as to how to get round this problem.
As in the case above, the `CSS` file is like this:

```
.theTable {display:table}
.theRow {display:table-row;} 
.cell1 {display:table-cell}
.cell2 {display:table-cell}
.cell1Content {display:block; height:10em; background:blue;}
.cell2Content {display:block; background:yellow; height:5em; margin-top:2em;}
```

If you change the last line (`margin-top:0em`) you'll see, it is not only the child that is changing size, but also the parent. I don't understand why? And what can be done about it?

Comment: Side note: If you have table-like data to show, it's perfectly legit to use actual `table`, `tr` and `td` elements for that. The "no tables" dogma is about (ab)using tables for positioning sections of the document.

Comment: Also, I don't completely get what you mean by 'enlarging upward'. Could it be that your cells have a [`vertical-align: bottom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)? If so, set it to `top` or `baseline` (or the other way around).

Comment: well, if you run the style sheet code from my question, once with the last line `margin-top:2em;` and once with `margin-top:0em;`, you'll see that instead of the `2em` space moving the content "DOWNWARD", it is in fact moving the table's top border "UPWARD", effectively enlarging the table while there is still plenty of room at the bottom of the same cell. I don't understand why the content doesn't use this space to move "DOWNWARD", rather the table, itself, is resizing!

Comment: I tried this code, but either I don't get the question, or it doesn't reproduce what you mean. Have you tried this in a stand-alone context, like a Stack Snippet or a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is that the cells start from bottom to grow upwards right?

Something like this could solve it:
http://jsfiddle.net/7y19n8eh/

```
.theTable {display:table}
.theRow {display:table-row;} 
.cell1 {display:table-cell;vertical-align: bottom}
.cell2 {display:table-cell;vertical-align: bottom}
.cell1Content {display:block; height:10em; background:blue;}
.cell2Content {display:block; background:yellow; height:5em; margin-top:2em;}
```

What I did was to add vertical-align:bottom to the cells.
The vertical-align property sets the vertical alignment of an element and is compatible with all major browsers.

Comment: No, that's not my point. I do NOT want the content to start from the bottom, rather I want them to fill the `table-cell` as far as there is space in the `table-cell`. So `vertical-align:bottom` is not the answer (moreover, I don't know the height of my elements)/

Comment: Well can you provide a jsfiddle that shows the issue?

Comment: thank you @Sneakybastardd. It's funny that the behavior on jdfiddle is what I want, but on my pc, it beaves differently. Sounds like the problems must be with my browser or something like that!

Comment: It's probably other css that is causing it, use the inspector and disable css styles until you find the issue.

Comment: You're right @sneakybastardd. I had an extra `margin:0px 0px 10% 0px` in my styes which caused the content not to move downward. Instead the table was resizing due to the 10% bottom margin. Removing that solved the problem.